# How To Show Image In Image Tag In Asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I Have tried this code for image showing in image tag it's not showing the Image Help Me

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "Select Image From tablename";
cmd.Connection = Connection.con;
Connection.con.Open();

byte[] bytes = (byte[])cmd.ExecuteScalar();
string strbasestring = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
imgsubcon1.ImageUrl = "data:Image/png;base64," + strbasestring;
Connection.con.Close();
```

Comment: Your code doesn't compile for a start...

Comment: Do you receive an error? What does your rendered output look like? Does the image tag contain anything at all?

Comment: No Error Image Tag Is Like This   <asp:Image runat="server" ID="imgsubcon1" />

Comment: your extension is png, try to change this? And try to change data:Image to data:image

Comment: I have tried but image not showing changed to image and png to jpg

Comment: Can you send your strbasestring result?

Comment: An alternative design might be to store the images on disk, rather than in the database. In the database, just store info that lets you locate the image (e.g. filename and/or path). Then you wouldn't have this issue because you'd just populate the src property of the image tag (.ImageUrl for an asp:Image control) with the URL to the image.